# Using list comprehension to update list in a for loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to update a list using for loop, I understand that it does not work but am unsure what is the best way to do it.

```
l = ['axy','axy','bxy','cxy']

for i in l:

    item = 'ax'
    l = [s for s in l if not s.startswith(item)]
    print l
```

Output:

```
['bxy', 'cxy']
['bxy', 'cxy']
['bxy', 'cxy']
['bxy', 'cxy']
```

Expected Output:

```
['bxy', 'cxy']
['bxy', 'cxy'] 
['bxy', 'cxy'] 

#1 less loop as the list should've been updated to l = ['bxy','cxy'] after the first loop
```

It tells me that the list gets updated but the iteration does not, is there anyway I can use list comprehension in the loop?

I am using this to remove files, so when the file is removed, I need to update the list so it does not get prompted again.

Comment: remove the last `print l`

Comment: Hi edited my code, shows more clearly what I want now.

Answer (score 3):

You are iterating a list with four items and upon each iteration you're printing the list - that's the first 4 prints. The last one is coming from the last line in the program:  `print l`.

The four iterations come from the fact that the list, while entering the loop, had 4 items. *That* list is being iterated while inside the loop you're just overriding the pointer to the list `l` (the original list still exist only now, after you're re-assigned `l` you can't access it anymore).

Comment: If I use something like remove instead, will it count as overriding and still wont be accessible?

Comment: @BernardL if you'll use `remove` you'll be modifying the list you're iterating and that might cause different kind of issues. Try to ask the question in a way that describes *what* you want to achieve and not *how* you're trying to do it. There might be other (simpler) ways to achieve your goal, like constructing a new list and adding to it only items that you're interested in.

Answer (score -1):

This is because assignment always create a new reference and does not update list in place.

When the for loop was evaluated `l` was replaced by its current value. Now this does not happen every iteration of loop. It only occurs once.

Whey you changed the value of `l` inside the loop using '=' it created the new reference, so the name `l` point to a different list altogether. It does not affect the list which was already evaluate in for loop.

If you use operation which updates the list inplace like `update` and `remove` you will see the output which you are expecting

Comment: I am just trying to explain what is happening in his code.